# ¿Cómo puedo codificar una cadena con Php?

Tags: php, base64, md5

Tengo este código BASH

```
get_customer_url() {
  local IP=${1:-127.0.0.1}
  local SECRET=${2:-VERY_COOL_SECRET}
  local EXPIRES="$(date -d "today + 30 minutes" +%s)";
  local token="$(echo -n "${EXPIRES} ${IP} ${SECRET}" | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =)"
  echo "https://example.com/video/hls/${token}/${EXPIRES}/live.m3u8"
}
```

Y estoy queriendo hacer este mismo código pero en Php. Practicamente lo estoy intentando hacer pero en la parte de la encriptacion con md5 y base64 me estoy perdiendo. he logrado hacer que imprima pero no queda igual al resultado del script BASH

Este es el código php que logré hacer:

```
<?php

$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$secret = 'VERY_COOL_SECRET';
$expires = time()+30*60;
$token1 = md5("$expires $ip $secret");
$token1 = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($token1), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
echo $token1 ;
```

Devuelve una cadena similar a esta:

```
NTJjNzg4YThlMzA5ZjhjZTJjMDM3YzdkYTE1M2YzMTQ
```

pero con el Bash queda así:

```
Z35QX0iDntGvUD8GYbzxuw
```

¿Alguien que pueda convertirme este codigo a php o ayudarme con el codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$secret = 'VERY_COOL_SECRET';
$expires = time()+30*60;
$str = "$expires $ip $secret"; // string
$base64 = base64_encode(md5($str,true)); // convertimos a md5 binario y luego a base64 
$remove_slash = preg_replace('/\/+/m', '_', $base64); // remplazamos los slash por underline
$token = preg_replace('/=/m', '',$remove_slash);  // removemos los simbolos de igual
echo $token;
```

**codigo bash `cast.sh`:**

```
get_customer_url() {
  local IP=${1:-127.0.0.1}
  local SECRET=${2:-VERY_COOL_SECRET}
  local EXPIRES="$(date -d "today + 30 minutes" +%s)";
  echo -n "${EXPIRES} ${IP} ${SECRET}" # linea prueba
  echo "";
  local token="$(echo -n "${EXPIRES} ${IP} ${SECRET}" | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =)"
  echo $token
  echo "";
  #echo "https://example.com/video/hls/${token}/${EXPIRES}/live.m3u8"
}

get_customer_url
```

**resultado:**

```
1560400267 127.0.0.1 VERY_COOL_SECRET
RZpwvIF2CH5mucjHrHAqDg
```

**prueba completa:**

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$secret = 'VERY_COOL_SECRET';
$expires = time()+30*60;
$str = "$expires $ip $secret"; // string
$base64 = base64_encode(md5($str,true)); // convertimos a md5 binario y luego a base64 
$remove_slash = preg_replace('/\/+/m', '_', $base64); // remplazamos los slash por underline
$token = preg_replace('/=/m', '',$remove_slash);  // removemos los simbolos de igual
echo shell_exec("./cast.sh"); // ejecutamos el script bash
echo $token;
echo "\n";
```

**resultado:**

```
4TNmduhv00lO_BS9LsWvBA

4TNmduhv00lO_BS9LsWvBA
```

Comment: Gracias amigo con esto lo logre $base64 = base64_encode(md5($str,true));